# return is not allowed here when authenticating using okhttp

Tags: android, kotlin, authentication, okhttp, refresh-token

I'm trying to implement a refresh token process. Basically i have an access token that expires in an hour, and a refresh token which i send to the server in order to get a new access token.

I'm using okhttp as my http client and it has built in support for authentication, but the problem is that in the authenticate method I have to return a Request object with the new access token inside.
To do this, first i must wait for an api call to retrieve the new access token using the refresh token that i provide, and as you know, this process takes a while to complete.

My question is how can I wait for the result to come, and then return my Request object?

```
class TokenAuthenticator : Authenticator {

override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {

    //With RX
    val newToken = getTokenFromServer()?.doOnSuccess {
        return response.request().newBuilder().url("URL").addHeader("token", it.result?.token)
            .build()
    }

    //First coroutine attempt
    val job = runblocking { launch { getTokenFromServer() } }
    job.join()
    //... create request
    return request
    
    //Second coroutine attempt
    val request = runBlocking { 
        val newToken = getTokenFromServer()
        //... create new request object here using newToken
        return@runBlocking request
    }
    return request
}

fun getTokenFromServer(): Single<ApiResponse>? {
    //... gets data from server and returns the result
    return newToken
}
}
```

side notes:

1. When using RX, I can't return a request object from inside the doOnSuccess.
2. In first coroutine attempt, using job.join() requires the authenticate method to be a suspend function, and I am not allowed to change it.
3. In second coroutine attempt it seems to be ok but doesn't it block the UI thread doing it this way? or since the whole process is happening outside of the UI thread the app won't freeze!?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you should not put any asynchronous code in the authenticator. You just need to wrap entire call (the one for which you set the authenticator) in RxJava type and you will be fine. (Use retrofit + Retrofit RxJava adapter)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more please? What do you mean by wrapping the entire call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, since we are already on a background thread, we can use synchronous tasks and wait for the response.

```
override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {

    //With RX
    val newToken = getTokenFromServer().blockingGet()
    return newToken

    //Or a retrofit call object
    val newToken = getTokenFromServer().execute()
    return newToken
}
```